# Bind TextBox to decimal-property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my application I have a `TextBox` where the user can input a number beetween 1 and 10. The xaml of this `TextBox` looks like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="tbInput"/>
```

The property Value where the `TextBox` is bound to looks like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(decimal), typeof(NumericUpDown), new PropertyMetadata((d, e) =>
        {
            ((NumericUpDown)d).Value = (decimal)e.NewValue;
        }));

public decimal Value
{
    get { return (decimal)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set
    {
        if (Value == value || value > Maximum || value < Minimum)
            return;
        SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        OnValueChanged();
    }
}
```

It works if the user types in a number. But if the user types in a char or a string or something else than it doesn't work. I expected that my `TextBox` wouldn't accept the invalid value but a breakpoint in the setter of the Value-Property is not reached.

What do I have to do to only allow numbers or to decline the user-input if it's not correct?

Comment: The easiest way is to use 3rd party `***UpDown` controls (e.g., from Extended WPF Toolkit). If you want some hardcore, then inherit from `TextBox` and filter user input.

Comment: Where is this code, in a view model or in code-behind of a UserControl? You are mixing dependency properties with INotifyPropertyChanged. You should choose one way or the other but not both.

Comment: The code is in the code-behind-file. The datacontext of the xaml is bound to the code-behind-file with `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
((NumericUpDown)d).Value = (decimal)e.NewValue;
```

in the PropertyChangedCallback doesn't make sense, because it just sets the Value property another time to the same value.

You should instead move the code from the property setter to the callback. Moreover, you should not call anything but `SetValue` in the setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The reason is explained in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) article on MSDN.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(decimal), typeof(NumericUpDown),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            (d, e) =>
            {
                ((NumericUpDown)d).OnValueChanged();
            }));

public decimal Value
{
    get { return (decimal)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value);}
}
```

---

In order to validate the value passed to your dependency property, you may use the [DependencyProperty.Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501.aspx) overload that takes a `ValidateValueCallback` argument:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value", typeof(decimal), typeof(MainWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata((d, e) => ((NumericUpDown)d).OnValueChanged()),
        v => (decimal)v >= Minimum && (decimal)v <= Maximum);
```